# Is this the way to compute the row wise standard deviation in Polars?

Tags: list, aggregation, python-polars, rowwise

I am wondering if this is the optimal way to calculate the standard deviation across rows in Polars:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "entity_id":["A","A","A","B","B"],
        "cons_level":["CON","CON","CON","CON","CON"],
        "reported_period": [
            datetime(2022, 6, 30),
            datetime(2022, 9, 30),
            datetime(2022, 12, 31),
            datetime(2022, 3, 31),
            datetime(2022, 6, 30),
        ],
        "integer": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "A": [4.0, None, None, 7.0, 8.0],
        "C": [6.0, None, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0],
        "D": [4.0, None, 12.0, 70.0, 11.0],
    }
)

df.select(pl.concat_list("A", "C",'D').list.eval(pl.element().std()).list.get(0))
```

It looks odd to me.

I tried to calculate the row wise standard deviation on a polars data frame. The line i came up with seems odd to me. Is there a faster approach ?

Comment: There is a feature request to add `.list.std()`and others: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9033 - do you think `pl.concat_list("A", "C",'D').list.std()` would still look odd?

Comment: thank you for sharing the request, no that seems fine. By stating i looks odd, i was more doubting my own usage of polars ;)

Answer (score 0):

**This probably doesn't look any less odd but it *is* more performant.**

First, assign a column to represent the row index, then melt your desired columns using the newly created row index. With that you do a groupby on the row index and then agg to get the standard deviation.

```
(
    df
        .with_row_count('i')
        .melt(id_vars='i', value_vars=['A','C','D'])
        .groupby('i')
        .agg(pl.col('value').std().alias('std'))
        .sort('i')
        .drop('i')
)
```

If you wanted to add that column to the original df then you'd do a self join and move the sort and drop to after the join like this...

```
(
    df.with_row_count('i')
        .join(
            df
                .with_row_count('i')
                .melt(id_vars='i', value_vars=['A','C','D'])
                .groupby('i')
                .agg(pl.col('value').std().alias('std')),
            on='i'
        )
    .sort('i')
    .drop('i')                
)
```

**Performance Comparison**:

I setup this df

```
df=pl.DataFrame({
    'entity_id':np.random.choice(['A','B'], size=1000000),
    "reported_period": np.random.choice([
            datetime(2022, 6, 30),
            datetime(2022, 9, 30),
            datetime(2022, 12, 31),
            datetime(2022, 3, 31),
            datetime(2022, 6, 30),
        ], size=1000000),
    'integer':np.arange(1,1000001,1),
    'A':np.random.normal(0,1,1000000),
    'C':np.random.normal(2,5,1000000),
    'D':np.random.normal(3,10,1000000),
                })
```

then I did OP's code except that I swapped `select` with `with_columns` utilizing `concat_list` and that took `895 ms ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` when using `%%timeit`

I ran my code and it took `415 ms ± 30.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

The point is that, perhaps counter-intuitively, melts, joins, and groupbys are actually quite efficient in polars whereas concat_list, and list.eval are relatively inefficient.

Another look is to convert the df to lazy and then run `.profile` (instead of `.collect`)

With OP's method the profile is:

```
┌──────────────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ node             ┆ start ┆ end     │
│ ---              ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str              ┆ u64   ┆ u64     │
╞══════════════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ optimization     ┆ 0     ┆ 266     │
│ with_column(std) ┆ 266   ┆ 1093201 │
└──────────────────┴───────┴─────────┘
```

With mine, it is:

```
┌──────────────────────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ node                     ┆ start  ┆ end    │
│ ---                      ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str                      ┆ u64    ┆ u64    │
╞══════════════════════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ optimization             ┆ 0      ┆ 9      │
│ MELT                     ┆ 9      ┆ 52264  │
│ FAST_PROJECT: [value, i] ┆ 52269  ┆ 52388  │
│ groupby(i)               ┆ 52393  ┆ 209762 │
│ join(i)                  ┆ 209778 ┆ 441006 │
│ sort(i)                  ┆ 441523 ┆ 619179 │
│ DROP                     ┆ 619184 ┆ 619190 │
└──────────────────────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

Lastly, [here's an issue](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7124) that was raised about (at the time) `.arr.eval`, now renamed `list.eval` being slow.

The important part of that link is this from the ritchie

> You are using arr.eval in one example. That is expected to be much slower as it is opaque to us what you are doing. arr.eval should be seen as last resort.

Comment: I indeed want to add the standard deviation as a column. It seems that the join is quite costly, i think for now ill run with my approach.

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: When you say it seems costly, did you actually run it?

Comment: yes i did:
my line to create the column:

`788 µs ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10,000 loops each)`

vs
using the join:
`1.07 ms ± 147 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 10,000 loops each)`

i could imagine that this gets worse if i have much more rows, but admittedly i didnt test on more rows yet.

Comment: @VicVic are you sticking to your story that the time difference of, checks notes, less than a millisecond is "quite costly"?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to reply to you. I checked on much larger data sets and your approach is faster @DeanMacGregor. 

Im new: both to polars and stack overflow. I did not mean any disrespect.